# How to create a path over a GoogleMap using symfony2 and IvoryGoogleMap bundle?

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony

I'm using symfony2 for a project in which I have to create path(itineraries) using GoogleMaps. I've seen that the recomendation for doing this in symfony2 is IvoryGoogleMap bundle but I need some Idea in order to start.
I have installed symfony2 correctly and I have also configured the above mentioned bundle. 
I need to mark a point over the map making dobleclick. After that, mark other points in order to make a path. 
Could somebody help me with this?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the part about the [polyline](https://github.com/egeloen/ivory-google-map/blob/master/doc/usage/overlays/polyline.md) in the documentation?

Creating a initial polyline/path is very easy with the bundle. A little example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template
 */
public function homeAction()
{
    $map = $this->get('ivory_google_map.map');

    $polyline = $this->get('ivory_google_map.polyline');

    // get your path coordinates from where you want or have it
    foreach ($something->getCoordinates() as $lineCoordinates) {
        // addCoordinate(latitude, longitude)
        $polyline->addCoordinate($lineCoordinates[1], $lineCoordinates[0]);
    }

    $map->addPolyline($polyline);

    return array('map' => $map);
}
```

**But** if you have to add something to the map after loading the site, it's out of the scope of symfony and you have to work with the [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).